# Django Errors, Login and Signup forms works with standard methods but not with Class Based Views

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I wanted to ask you for your help. I wanted to rewrite my authentication with Class Based Views. I found several tutorials, they are all telling the same.
urls.py:

```
# Authorization:
path('signup/', views.SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView, name='logout'),
```

views.py:

```
class SignUpView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    template_name = 'registration/signup.html'
```

And this is part of my signup.html:

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid vertical-center">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">

            {% if error %}
                <div style="text-align: center;">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{ error }}</div>
                </div>
            {% endif %}

            <div class="row w-75">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h1>Sign Up:</h1><br>
                    <form method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Username:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                                   placeholder="Enter username. It will be visible for others." required>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password1" id="exampleInputPassword1"
                                   placeholder="Password. Please make it strong and unique." required>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Confirm Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password2" id="exampleInputPassword1"
                                   placeholder="Repeat password from above." required>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Sign Up</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And it is not working. I can see in console that `POST 200` was sent but there is no redirect to home page. When I try to login, nothing is happening. Also no errors are showing up (for mismatch in passwords etc.) and I cannot find any tutorial or article that would show implementation for showing errors to the user.

I don't understand where I made a mistake. Because on tutorials (beside not showing any errors to user) they at least have working redirect and successful user creation.

Where did I make a mistake?

Edit:

UserCreationForm in forms.py:
(I believe that I did not made any changes here)

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
"""
A form that creates a user, with no privileges, from the given username and
password.
"""
error_messages = {
    'password_mismatch': _('The two password fields didn’t match.'),
}
password1 = forms.CharField(
    label=_("Password"),
    strip=False,
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'new-password'}),
    help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html(),
)
password2 = forms.CharField(
    label=_("Password confirmation"),
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'new-password'}),
    strip=False,
    help_text=_("Enter the same password as before, for verification."),
)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ("username",)
    field_classes = {'username': UsernameField}

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self._meta.model.USERNAME_FIELD in self.fields:
        self.fields[self._meta.model.USERNAME_FIELD].widget.attrs['autofocus'] = True

def clean_password2(self):
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
    if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        raise ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
            code='password_mismatch',
        )
    return password2

def _post_clean(self):
    super()._post_clean()
    # Validate the password after self.instance is updated with form data
    # by super().
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
    if password:
        try:
            password_validation.validate_password(password, self.instance)
        except ValidationError as error:
            self.add_error('password2', error)

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super().save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

Comment: show us the ```UserCreationForm()```

Comment: Hi, I edited my post with this function. But I believe that it is a built in and I did not edit that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you're handling the form in the view?

```
class SignUpView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    template_name = 'registration/signup.html'
```

Doesn't have any form handling method.

Try:

```
class SignUpView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    template_name = 'registration/signup.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       form_class = self.get_form_class()
       form = self.get_form(form_class)
       if form.is_valid():
           form.save()  //handle user creation here. 
       return self.form_valid(form)
```

Comment: I added this code and it seems that it is working now, but I am confused. I did similar things with my previous method approach (I am making sure that passwords matches, passing errors to context etc.). But all of those tutorials and articles explained that with class based approach I wouldn't have to make those things. I thought that just because of that this CBVs are better?

Comment: It's fine to do it the above way, you're just overriding the form handling, you can do it at times to insert extra code.

Comment: @Peksio if this helped please mark as the correct answer.

Comment: @Anthony Hi, I am sorry I did not mark this answer as accepted. I just think that while this works, it's not the best approach? Because I think that it should be handled by django itself, without this additional code?

Comment: @Peksio Why don't you read the documentation and you'll find out that using methods to handle forms is a very acceptable way of doing things. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/

Comment: @Anthony Thank you, I will check out this documentation. But the thing is, when it stopped working I started watching several tutorials and in none of them there was a need for manually handling post definitions etc. Did something change in django recently?

Comment: @Peksio No. CreateView can handle Post requests, however only in the most basic of use-cases. For example if you needed to run some function upon a user signing up, such as emailing them a confirmation, `CreateView` wouldn't be able to do this, and you would need to override it's `post` method as I have in my answer to achieve this. You will often find yourself overriding CBVs functions to achieve additional functionality, and it is not bad practise.

Comment: @Anthony Oh, to be honest I am shocked ... I heard that standard "method approach" (with checking if passwords are matching) is totally non-Django and non-Pythonic but with overriding this post function it seems that the difference is getting kinda small between those two. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Peksio I don't know what hearsay you're referring to, but the documentation is pretty clear. It's best to get your information from there.

Comment: @Anthony I think that you are right. Thank you for this talk, your time and for your answer.